# Showing whether an $L^\infty$ function is in $L^2$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $(X,\mathcal{M},\mu)$ be a measure space, and suppose $g\in L^{\infty}(X)$. If for every function $f\in L^{2}(X)$, we always have
$$\int |f\overline{g}|\,\mathrm{d}\mu <\infty,$$
(i.e., $f\overline{g}\in L^{1}(X)$) then does $g$ necessarily lie in $L^{2}(X)$?

This question is asking a partial converse of the general fact that $L^{2}(X)$ usually forms a Hilbert space with the inner product $\langle f, g\rangle = \int f\overline{g}\,\mathrm{d}\mu$, provided that $f,g\in L^{2}(X)$.

Comment: Is the integral allowed to be $-\infty$?

Comment: @Jose27 good point! I have edited my question.

Comment: One way is to appeal to the uniform boundedness principle. But you can also give a more elementary proof: assume not then build a sequence that violates the boundedness of the "inner product" with $g$, normalize your sequence appropriately and use weak convergence properties in $L^2$.

Comment: @Jose27: What continuous operator are you applying Banach Steinhaus to?

Comment: @copper.hat we consider the family $l_r(f) =\int f1_{A_r} \bar{g} d\mu$, where the $A_r$ are a family of finite measure sets. This is a pointwise bounded family of continuous functionals on $L^2$ since $g\in L^\infty$.

Comment: By truncating $g$ at appropriate heights we could also dispense of the bounded $g$ condition.

Comment: @Jose27: I don't see how you get $\sup_r |l_r(f)| < \infty$. That is the essence of the problem.

Comment: @copper.hat $$ |l(f) |\leq \int _{A_r} |fg|d\mu\leq \int_X |fg|d\mu<\infty.$$

Comment: @Jose27: Wow, I am slow today. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For any $f \in L^2(X)$, $\int |fg| d \mu = \int|\bar{f}\bar{g}| d\mu < \infty$ ( Using the fact that $\forall f \in L^2(X)$ we have that $f\bar{g} \in L^1(X)$ )

Hence, $\forall f \in L^2(X), |\int fg d\mu| \le \int|fg|d \mu < \infty$ , in other words, the sending $f \mapsto \int fg d\mu$ defines a bounded linear functional on $L^2(X)$ . Since, $L^2(X)^* \cong L^2(X)$ , it follows that $g \in L^2(X)$ .

Comment: Don't we need to check that this defines a *continuous* linear functional?

Comment: Indeed, $g \in L^2$ **iff** $f \mapsto \int \bar{g}f$ is continuous.

Comment: For linear applications, bounded functional = continuous functional